# How can i take src value from jquery zoom using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I tried with

```
$content =file_get_contents("http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom");
preg_match('/<img[\s\S][^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*id="zoom1"[^>]*>/',$content,$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

it returns empty array but when take only the html part and tested with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/6e318Wb0II)
it gives the correct output.Please help to figure it out

Comment: show us some sample content returned from $content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
/\<img.*?id\=["\']zoom1["\'].*?src\=["\'](.+?)["\'][\s]{0,}.*?\/{0,1}\>/ims
```

if it returns false, they try this:

```
/\<img.*?src\=["\'](.+?)["\'][\s]{0,}.*?id\=["\']zoom1["\'].*?\/{0,1}\>/ims
```

.

Basically, the regex will be highly dependent upon the order of the id and src.

However, since we are dealing with html here, it would be better to use DOM/XPath instead.

Comment: /\<img[\s]{0,}.*?src\=["\'](.+?)["\'][\s]{0,}.*?id=["\']zoom1["\']\/{0,1}\>/ it returns nothing ...its not working.

Comment: thats because you didnt tell me there was a "class" after id. But looking at Rubular, now I have updated it. check now

Comment: $content = file_get_contents("http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom");
preg_match_all('/\<img[\s]{0,}.*?src\=["\'](.+?)["\'][\s]{0,}.*?id\=["\']zoom1["\'][\s]{0,}.*?\/{0,1}\>/ims',$content,$arr);
print_r($arr);
this is what i tested but it seems to be not working.

Comment: ok got it. Thats because the `id=zoom1` is coming before src.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DOM instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$src = $xpath->query('//img[@id="zoom1"]')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Really so much easier and the right approach to use =)

Comment: I know its working, but i need regex instead of xpath.Any way thanks for your answer..